# Wrapping class methods that use transactions

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, transactions

I have multiple class methods that each use transactions and rollbacks if exceptions are thrown. Basic example below.

```
class TaskMapper
{
    private $dblayer;

    public function __construct(PDO $dblayer)
    {
        $this->dblayer = $dblayer;
    }

    public function save(Task $task)
    {
        try {
            $this->dblayer->beginTransaction();

            $stmt = ... // query/queries here
            $stmt->execute();

            $stmt2 = ... // query/queries here
            $stmt2->execute();

            $this->dblayer->commit();

        } catch (\PDOException $e) {

            $this->dblayer->rollBack();
            // deal with exception here
        }


    }

    public function editField($id, $field, $value)
    {
        try {
            $this->dblayer->beginTransaction();

            $stmt = ... // query/queries here
            $stmt->execute();

            $stmt2 = ... // query/queries here
            $stmt2->execute();

            $stmt->execute();

            $this->dblayer->commit();

        } catch (\PDOException $e) {

            $this->dblayer->rollBack();
            // deal with exception here
        }
    }

}
```

Now, I am writing a script for a cron job which utilises multiple class methods that contain code similar to the above - with transactions and rollbacks, and exceptions.

For example:

```
if (date('j') == '1') {
    // reset monthly count column
    $task->editField(17, 'monthly_count', '0');
}
$task->save($task);
```

This is a very stripped back example, but I would like to know if it is possible to wrap all of the method calls within a single transaction within a try/catch block, and rollback within the catch? So wrap the code above in a try/catch with a transaction and a rollback in the catch?

If not, what is the best way to approach a situation like this where if one method call fails, the others MUST be rolled back.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To me the presence of the save() method implies that all database transactions would be handled from that call. Up to that point changes are only done in the php objects level. The role of the save() would be to persists the changes and therefore that would wrap all queries into a single transaction.

Answer (score 1):

I rather add an answer because comments are too short to explain.

Basically, you have 2 ways to approach encompassing multiple operations within a single transaction from an application.

1. Call a method that starts a transaction. Each subsequent method calls, property changes result in a change in the database. Any errors during these operations would result in a rollback. In the end you call another method that commits the entire transaction.
2. Every method call, property change changes the php object state only, so the database is not changed. After you are satisfied with all the changes, you call a single method, that persists **all** changes to the database. Rollback / commit is also performed in this call.

Mysql does not support nested transactions, so either you use the first method in conjunction with [PDO:inTransaction](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.intransaction.php) as @YourCommonSense also suggested by initiating a transaction before calling editField(), or you have to take out the database modification codes from the editField() and similar calls and use only save().

Comment: Thanks for this - will try these out and mark as correct, may have a couple more questions though!

Answer (score 0):

I never used it myself, but there is a [`PDO::inTransaction`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.intransaction.php) method, which you can use to see whether there is a higher level transaction is started.

So you can change to

```
if ( !$this->dblayer->inTransaction() ) {
    $this->dblayer->beginTransaction();
}
```

and so for commit as well.

which will let you decide, whether "local" transaction have to be used, and thus make it possible to use a "global" transaction to wrap all these methods together.

Comment: This would not be a bad idea, however, there is no indication in the OP that task would start and keep an encompassing transaction open. Therefore inTransaction() would return false.

Comment: @Shadow Could you explain what you mean here - regarding keeping transaction open? Thanks

Comment: inTransaction() returns true if there is an open transaction. However, both your save() and editField() methods have their own start transactions and commits. The only way inTransaction() would be useful, if you started a database transaction **before** you call either start() or editField().

Comment: @Shadow do you mean in the class file or in the cron script?

Comment: @CIvemy check out the answer I just posted